# How to detect undefined DataTemplate that is referenced by other DataTemplate that is dynamically loaded?

Tags: wpf

In our application we dynamically load some DataTemplates at runtime based on use cases. And these DataTemplate refers to another layer of DataTemplates, and this can go on for two or three layers.
Since there are many DataTemplate definitions, we might miss defining one of lower layer DataTemplates.

The bad thing is that VisualStudio does not warn the missing DataTemplate and the build goes OK without related warning and the exception throws at run time.

Without compiler aid, it's purely human diligence to get bug-free code.
Any tools can help to detect undefined but referenced DataTemplate?

Thanks a lot.

For example the following simplifed XAML illustrate the problem. Layer1 DataTemplates refers to Layer2 DataTemplates. Layer1_0x00010D83_Layer2List_0x00010712_0x00010719 is loaded dynamically at run time, it refer to Layer2_0x00010712 and Layer2_0x00010719. If Layer2_0x00010719 is not defined, then the compiling goes OK, but throws error at run time.

```
    <DataTemplate  x:Key="Layer2_0x00010712">
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}"
                       Style="{StaticResource NameTextBlockStyle}"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Layer1_0x00010D83_Layer2List_0x00010712_0x00010719">
        <local:Layer1Border x:Name="" Layer1ID="0x00010D83" >
            <Grid>
                <local:Layer2Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                    <Button Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Layer2_0x00010712}"/>
                </local:Layer2Border>
                <local:Layer2Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                    <Button Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Layer2_0x00010719}"/>
                </local:Layer2Border>
            </Grid>
        </local:Layer1Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: `Layer1_0x00010D83_Layer2List_0x00010712_0x00010719` - Best WPF resource name in the history of mankind. Yes, Visual Studio warns you that a specific `StaticResource` could not be resolved at compile time. Otherwise use ReSharper.

Comment: There is no related warning on missing StaticResource in this case, I'm using VisualStudio2008. We use the number to avoid duplication of IDs which are coordinated in multiple platforms, they match certain names behind. I will give a try of ReSharper. Thanks.

Comment: Update your IDE. Visual Studio 2013 just when RTM. You're 3 versions behind.